# hibernate validator LengthValidator of truncated string

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-validator

Is there a similar annotation to `@Length` in hibernate validator but it restricted on a trimmed string.

For example:

I have

```
@Length(max= 2);
String str;
```

when: 
`str = " ab"`;
--> it will pass ok.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As fare i know, there isn't one.

But you can easely implement your own.

The other (not so good) way is to add a getter which trim the string.

```
@Length(max= 2);
String getTrimmedStr() {
   return this.str.trim();
}
```

But i think implementing your own Validator is the much cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but you can easily implement one with `javax.validation`, by extending the `LengthValidator`