# Detecting string overlength in advance

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate to persist data decoded from file inputs. Since one of our format is a variable-length format, I'd like to easily check for possible insertion errors in the entity **before** the transaction gets committed, so I can handle exceptions and take appropriate actions.

If I have an entity

```
@Entity
public class Entity {

    @Column(...,length=20)
    private String col1;

    @Column(...,length=20)
    private String col2;

    @Column(...,length=40)
    private String col3;

    ...

    @Column(...,length=100)
    private String col..N;

}
```

I'd like to detect if the `String` I set as value of each column is compatible with its length, possibly without instrumenting Java code to validate each and every field against the max length.

Currently, I only get a SQL exception when transaction is committed (i.e. `@Transactional` method returns) for the whole batch when only a single record is affected by a problem. Catching an exception when I `Session.persist(entity)` would be appreciable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you already use Hibernate, have you considered [Hibernate Validator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-gettingstarted.html#validator-gettingstarted-createmodel)? It would look something like this

```
@Size(max = 20)
@Column(...,length=20)
private String col1;

// and validation itself
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
validator = factory.getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<Entity>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(entity);
```

Downside is that you would have to use another set of annotations beside `@Column`, but on the other hand it offers much more options.

Another option is to use [aspects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) and intercept every setter for `String` fields on classes annotated with `@Entity`. In the aspect you would get the `@Column` annotation and compare the parameter length with configured `lenght` attribute n the annotation.

Comment: Validation can be performed successfully in Lifecycle.onSave method, which must throw a CallbackException if validation fails

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom Interceptor to trim the Strings as suggested here:
[Properly handling long data in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882009/properly-handling-long-data-in-hibernate)

or maybe using the Length annotation and a custom Length validator as suggested here:
[hibernate validator LengthValidator of truncated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432719/hibernate-validator-lengthvalidator-of-truncated-string)

Comment: Actually I need to throw an exception rather than truncating. This way the user is informed about the circumstance